# Gehirn vs. Hirn

Tags: difference, noun, meaning

Gibt es zwischen den beiden Begriffen **Gehirn** und **Hirn** eigentlich Unterschiede?

*(Außer in der Schreibweise)*

Ist Hirn einfach nur eine Kurzform?
 
Gibt es Kontexte, in denen man einen Begriff bevorzugt?

Comment: Dieser [Dudeneintrag](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gehirn)  erwähnt, dass es sich bei Gehirn um ein [Kollektivum](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kollektivbildung) handelt.

Comment: Das ist nicht ganz korrekt. *Gehirn* ist nur der Herkunft nach ein Kollektivum, aber verwendet wird es nicht als Kollektivum, sondern bezeichnet eine einzelne Sache. Anders liegt der Fall z.B. bei *Berg* / *Gebirge*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Gehirn" benutzt man hauptsächlich für das Gehirn des Menschen.

"Hirn" dagegen bezieht sich meistens auf das Hirn eines Tieres, wobei oft das als Speise zubereitete Hirn eines Tieres gemeint ist. (http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hirn)

Comment: In der Umgangssprache gibt es Ausdruecke wie "hirnlos" oder "Hirnie". Diese sind zwar an einen Menschen gerichtet, doch denke ich dass sich diese von dem tierischen  Hirn ableiten, da sie beleidigend sein sollen.

Comment: Das hat noch nichts mit menschlichem und tierischem Gehirn zu tun! Hirn kann einfach auch im Sinne von "Verstand" oder "Geist" oder "Vernunft" verwendet werden, "Gehirn" dagegen nur für das Organ. Daher finde ich auch die Antwort hier nicht korrekt.

Comment: Die Frage war, ob es Kontexte gibt, in denen man einen Begriff bevorzugt. Meiner Meinung nach wird im tierischen Kontext "Hirn" häufiger benutzt als "Gehirn", einfach weil "Hirn" in der Küchensprache der gängige Begriff für die [Speise](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirn_(Lebensmittel)) ist.

Comment: a) Kann man in der Küche ebenso Gehirn sagen, und b) kann man Tiergehirne auch außerhalb des Küchenkontextes thematisieren, etwa bei Fragen der Vererbung, des Verhaltens, der Intelligenz. Außerdem ist der Mensch ein Tier.

Comment: Dann ist ein Hirnchirurg einfach nur ein Koch?

Comment: Meningitis (Hirnhautentzündung) / Das Virus wird ja auch oft durch Tiere übertragen. :)

Comment: @userunknown Ja kann man.  Ein Beispiel findest du im

Answer (score 12):

*Gehirn* und *Hirn* (als Kurzform) bezeichnen den menschlichen Denkapparat (unter natürlich auch den anderer Lebewesen). Daher werden beide Begriffe umgangssprachlich auch für *Verstand* benutzt.

Folglich der Definition nach kein Unterschied zwischen *Gehirn* und *Hirn*. Jedoch wird in der Praxis üblicherweise mit *Gehirn* der Denkapparat ansich bezeichnet (hinsichtlich Anatomie) und mit *Hirn* wird Bezug auf den Verstand oder das Denkvermögen genommen. Dadurch suggerieren insbesondere adjektivische Verwendung wie *hirnlos* und *gehirnlos* etwas unterschiedliches. Die Bedeutung ist aber stets aus dem Kontext zu entnehmen.

> Die Zombies laufen gehirnlos durch die Gegend.
>   Die Menschen laufen hirnlos durch die Gegend.

In der Gastronomie wird einzig *Hirn* verwendet, um das Lebensmittel zu beschreiben. Auch wenn laut Duden in einigen (nicht spezifizierten) Regionen *Gehirn* möglich ist. Diese Information kann man meiner Meinung nach aber getrost unter den Teppich kehren.

Answer (score 6):

#### Zusammenfassung

Im Allgemeinen können beide Begriffe `gleich benutzt` werden.
Beide können auch "abstrakte" Bedeutungen haben, wie `Denkvermögen`, `Verstand`, ... , `Begriffsvermögen`.

Laut dem [Duden-online](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gehirn) ist der Begriff **`Gehirn`** eine [Kollektivbildung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kollektivbildung) von **`Hirn`**.
 Demnach müsste `Gehirn` für mehrere Arten von "`Hirnen`" stehen.
Auf diese Art wird `Gehirn` zum Beispiel im entsprechenden [Wikipediaartikel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gehirn) benutzt.

- und Grimms Wörterbuch widerspricht dem mit:

> man hat zwar gehirn als coll. unterscheiden wollen, z. b. Frisch 1, 455b hirn cerebrum, gehirn tota cerebri massa, was schon Adelung mit recht ablehnte. aber ahd. hirni kann und wird selbst schon collectivisch sein mit seinem -i und n., s. sp. 1610 (γ a. e.), auch u. gehäsz, sodasz mit dem ge- die bezeichnung des collectivums nur nachträglich vervollständigt ward. vgl. übrigens das nrh. f. die hern u. a mit schwed. norw. hjerna f. nebst hjerne m. gegenüber dem n. des coll. (altn. hiarni n.). wegen der urverwandtschaft s. unter  1DWb  hirn 1, aus dem sanskr. vergleicht Fick3 1, 523 karn, karna topf, schüssel (s. 2, a).

Andererseits wird im `Kontext des Menschens` meist **`Gehirn`** benutzt, `Hirn` wirkt abwertend. (z.B. *Da ist nicht viel in seinem Hirn*)

#### Nahrungsmittel

Für Lebensmittel wird **Hirn**  bevorzugt (siehe:  [Duden-online](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hirn), [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirn_(Lebensmittel)))

#### Regionale Unterschiede

In einigen Regionen Deutschlands wird der Wunsch nach mehr Gehirn durch: 
*[Herr lass Hirn ra!](http://www.amazon.de/Herr-schmei%C3%9F-Hirn-schw%C3%A4bischen-Geschichten/dp/3421062579)* ausgedrückt.

#### Komposita

In Komposita wird auch beim menschlichen Gehirn *"Hirn-"* gegenüber *"Gehirn-"* bevorzugt:

- *Hirnforscher, Hirnblutung, Hirntumor, Hirnwindungen, Hirnhautentzündung etc.*

Aber es gibt auch Komposita in denen *"Hirn-"* nicht so gut funktioniert:

- *Gehirnerschütterung, Gehirnwäsche, ...*

#### Umgangssprache

Umgangssprachlich findet man fast ausschließlich *"Hirn"*, sowohl als allein stehender Begriff (*"Streng dein Hirn an!"*) als auch in Komposita:

- *Hirnschmalz, Hirnfurz, hirnverbrannt,...*

#### Etymologie

Interessanterweise leitet sich sowohl *Gehirn* als auch *Hirn* vom *Horn* ab, dem knochenartigen Auswuchs von Tieren am Kopf. Auch dafür gibt es schon seit dem Mittelhochdeutschen beide Varianten *"Horn"* und *"Gehörn"*.

Comment: **Downvoters:** There is nothing wrong with giving a summarizing answer to include comments or part-answers. Such answers, if good, should be encouraged rather than discouraged as they may turn out to become a so far missing complete answer to the question. This may then be helpful for other people who may come here by Google. In case we do not want to collect reputation points from copying other people's answers we may consider making such an answer "Community Wiki". Also see http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/292/what-may-be-the-desired-evolution-for-a-good-answer

Comment: M.E. kann man durchaus sagen: "Neben Einstein weilten auch andere, große Hirne bei der Konferenz."

Comment: @userunknown: hängt ganz von der Suche ab. Ich finde dort 9 "Gehirn"-Rezepte, von denen nicht eines "Hirn" als Zutat enthält. Von den 22 "Hirn" Rezepten enthalten immerhin mehr als die Hälfte tatsächlich Hirn.

Comment: @Takkat: Tatsache. Da ist ein Forum dahinter mit massig Diskussionen - ob etwas für's Hirn gut ist z.B., sogar Witze zum Hirn - nicht als Speise. Tatsache 5 Rezepte zu Gehirn, davon 2 angeblich förderlich für jenes, 3 sind falsches Hirn oder "sieht aus wie Hirn" für Halloween. Und 22x Hirn - nicht tausende Treffer.

Comment: Ein ähnliches Wortpaar ist _Darm_ und _Gedärm_, wobei _Gedärm_ das Kollektivum für die verschiedenen _Därme_ darstellt.

Answer (score 5):

*Gehirn* und *Hirn* können beide für das Organ an sich verwendet werden. *Hirn* wird aber auch im abstrakten Sinne von *Verstand* verwendet.

Answer (score 1):

Hier in der Gegend um Stuttgart hört man häufiger:

> Herr lass Hirn ra!

wenn mal wieder jemand etwas sehr dummes getan hat.

Comment: Steht "ra" für "regnen"? Das wäre dann die gängige Wendung.

Comment: Wenn *ra* die plattdeutsche Variante für *regnen* sein soll, dann muss der Rest der Wendung aber auch eingeplattdeutscht (geiles Wort) werden.

Comment: Seit wann spricht man in der Gegend um Stuttgart Platt?? also ehrlich. *"ra"* für *"herab"* ^.^

Comment: "ra" ist "herunter". Hat, außer der allgemeinen Richtung, mit "regnen" nix zu tun.

Answer (score 0):

Also ich kenne Hirn auch nur in der Verwendung als Bezeichnung für den Verstand, etwa in:

- Schalt dein Hirn ein

Was auch nicht zwangsläufig abwertend gemeint sein muss! Ich verwende es schließlich selbst auch für Situationen von Leichtsinn. Und leichtsinnig ist man soweit ich weiß nicht wenn man denkfaul ist, sondern wenn man voreilig, überstürzt, unbedacht, unbewusst oder unvorsichtig usw. agiert.

Kurz: **im Bezug auf Leichtsinnsfehler** etwa, (wie ich damals bei Diktaten. Ergo gab's fast immer 6er. Ich dachte nämlich meist in der Eile eher über die Leserlichkeit nach. Wenn ich schon schnell schreiben muss. Aber soviel erstmal zu einer fast überflüssigen Anekdote...)

Ich will damit eigentlich nur sagen: Ein Kommentar hat es bereits absolut richtig definiert. Leider konnte ich dem Beitrag von 10 Upvotes nicht den 11 Upvote geben. Daher diese extra Antwort.

Und Gehirn findet eigentlich ausschließlich für das Organ, umhüllt vom Schädelknochen, Verwendung.

Ausserdem sollten sich hier einige mal selbst hinterfragen, wenn sie den Unterschied von Gehirn und Hirn nach ihrer "Meinung" konstatieren. Was ich doch während dem Lesen als etwas grotesk empfunden habe... ^^
Vor allem schon deshalb, weil extra unter den sämtlichen Beiträgen steht man soll Antworten auf Grund von Meinungen unterlassen. Womit wir auch zu solchen Antworten sagen können:
Schaltet euer Hirn ein!

Aber nichts für ungut. Ich weiß in der heutigen Zeit ist es äußerst schwer, da die Meinung oft wichtiger zu sein scheint als das Wissen.